# Parse ISO 8601 time duration using Go (for instance PT90M)

Tags: go, duration, iso8601

Is there any easy way to convert an ISO 8601 string time duration (`P(n)Y(n)M(n)DT(n)H(n)M(n)S`) to `time.Duration`?

From [Wikipedia on ISO 8601 durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations):

> For example, "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" represents a duration of "three years, six months, four days, twelve hours, thirty minutes, and five seconds".

Comment: Parsing date/time strings is very well documented in Go. What have you tried? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: This question is particularly about ISO 8601 duration that is not supported in std lib.

Comment: KeyB0rys, here is an example https://play.golang.org/p/guybDGoJVrT with 3rd party lib.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no API in standard library for that, but there is a 3rd party library that can add ISO 8601 duration to a `time.Time`: https://godoc.org/github.com/senseyeio/duration#Duration.Shift.

ISO 8601 duration can not be generally converted to a `time.Duration` because it depends on the base `time.Time`.

https://play.golang.org/p/guybDGoJVrT

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/senseyeio/duration"
)

func main() {
    d, _ := duration.ParseISO8601("P1D")
    today := time.Now()
    tomorrow := d.Shift(today)
    fmt.Println(today.Format("Jan _2"))    // Nov 11
    fmt.Println(tomorrow.Format("Jan _2")) // Nov 12
}
```

Comment: The issue here is it doesn't give you an actual `time.Duration`. It has it however it's not exported.

Answer (score 2):

Finding existing solutions less than satisfactory I created [my own module](https://github.com/sosodev/duration) to parse ISO 8601 durations and convert them directly to a `time.Duration`. I hope you find it useful. :)

example usage: https://go.dev/play/p/Nz5akjy1c6W